# Disable flash on our website and in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, flash, iframe

## How can I disable flash from running in an iframe on my site?

We have a website where we give the user the option to view their site in an iframe on a makeshift mobile simulator. We wanted the user to see that their website doesn't look so great, but this doesn't work as intended for many reasons. I doesn't take into account meta-view port settings etc, but I'll figure that out later. The other problem is the flash works and don't want it to, so that they see that it wont run on iOS.

Comment: You can't. You don't have any control over what happens in iframes unless it's on the same domain.

Comment: Maybe you should just pay for an account with BrowserStack, and use their mobile emulators.

Comment: I do pay for browser stack.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum If you are confident that you cannot control what is in an iframe unless it is on the same domain, and you are confident that there is not routing or otherwise awesome trick, then you should commit this to an answer instead of a comment. I didn't expect it to be possible, however I would like confirmation that it is not.

Comment: @Barmar - We love BrowserStack. Is there some way of embedding that on a webpage and letting visitors type in their URL and see how their site looks on a little CSS version of an iPhone that I don't know about? One that is really fast and doesn't involve opening up a virtual server? If so, you could tell me about it and answer my question. I can't mark a comment as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminGruenbaum - now I can stop wondering.

Comment: BrowserStack has an API, but I haven't looked at it closely. I was assuming there's some way to make use of it for an application like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update - please see Rick's answer

The current HTML5 way is to use `sandbox="allow-scripts"` - this is explained in Rick's answer.

---

You can't control `iframe`s on another domain from your site.

You can't run any scripts on them to remove/alter flash because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

It's a security issue - imagine you could include and manipulate iframes. I could include an iframe containing http://nouveaus-bank.com and simulate events entering amounts and transferring money to my account in it.

There was an "allow-plugins" proposal for iframe sandboxing but it was [rejected](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=13032).

Your only option would be using a proxy on your site and putting it on your domain instead, or manipulating it on the server-side. If you can ask clients to include a code snippet on their side you can do a `.postMessage` and intercept it on the iframe asking it to remove the flash.

Comment: The "allow-plugins" proposal that was rejected was to *allow* plugins. All plugins (including flash) are currently disabled in all to spec sandboxed iframes. This would meet the OPs requirements unless they require other plugins to be operable.

Answer (score 2):

With the new HTML5 iframe sandbox attribute you can disable all plugins (including flash) in supported browswers by including the sandbox attribute. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>iframe{height:9000px; width:100%;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" src="http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Will not display the flash animation, or version information. But the same code without the sandbox will:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>iframe{height:9000px; width:100%;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yup, this is definitely the correct way, upvoted this, pinged the author in a comment to consider accepting this answer and edited mine. Truth be told I simply forgot my answer and did not update it when I understood the topic better. Thanks for the ping and for writing an answer.